# PHP opendir Sort files

Tags: php

I run this script on my localhost WAMP server and Bluehost

```
$dir = "../DB"
// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
```

In my localhost I get this output which is alphabetical.

```
filename:.
filename:..
filename:Autumn.xml
filename:background.xml
filename:backgroundclipsettings.xml
filename:Balloons.xml
filename:Beach.xml
filename:boy.xml
filename:boys.xml
filename:Christmas.xml
filename:city.xml
filename:clip
filename:clip.xml
```

But on Bluehost I get this order which I have no idea what's the criteria.

```
filename:SwirlsPink.xml
filename:OldPaper Orange.xml
filename:OldPaper Green.xml
filename:Lets Celebrate.xml
filename:Outdoor Activities.xml
filename:..
filename:Spring.xml
filename:Neutral.xml
filename:.
filename:SwirlsGreen.xml
filename:Sports.xml
```

Can anybody tell me what to do to get alphabetical order in bluehost, and why do I get different results ?

Comment: There is no sorting applied for opendir/readdir, and the files are read in whatever (random) order the underlying file system spits them out. Use `glob` instead, which sorts by default – or implement your own sorting by putting the entries into an array first and then sorting that array afterwards.

Comment: I can't use this, because, my function is recursive and I use the the folders' name after every call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell why you get different results (different filesystems lead to different results?)...

To sort the list, however, the only option is to create an intermediate array that holds all the files:

```
$dir = "../DB";
$allfiles = array();
// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      $allfiles[] = $file;
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
sort($allfiles);
foreach($allfiles as $file) {
  echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
}
```

EDIT:

This version is recursive:

```
function printFoldersRecursive($dir)
{
    $allfiles = array();

    // Open a directory, and read its contents
    if (is_dir($dir)){
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
                if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                    $allfiles[] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }

    sort($allfiles);

    foreach($allfiles as $file) {
        echo "filename:" . $dir.'/'.$file . "<br>\n";
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)){
            printFoldersRecursive($dir.'/'.$file);
        }
    }
}

printFoldersRecursive('../DB');
```

Comment: I can't use the sorting after the array, since my function is recursive and I get filenames based on ther levels.

Comment: @aminelasfar what do you mean with "based on their levels"? Anyway, it's possible to do that also on recursive functions

Comment: I meant by levels the children of parent directory. For each directory, I need to look inside it for child folder and do same operation on it again.

Comment: Thanks! This isn't my original function, but I was able to follow your pattern and apply it on my function, Thank You for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`scandir`](http://php.net/scandir) you can specify the sorting order:

```
$dir = "../DB"
if ( is_dir( $dir )) {
  $files = scandir( $dir, SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING );
  foreach( $file in $files ) {
    echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
  }
}
```